# Mimic FQDN on a home machine not on a domain

Tags: windows-10, hosts, fqdn

I have a home PC running Windows 10, no domain controller, and therefore by default I do not have a FQDN for the machine.

I am trying to setup some server software for testing purposes, and it requires that I use a FQDN.

**How can I manipulate my hosts file to mimic a FQDN?**

Extra info, please let me know in comments if you need more.

- There will be no other machines trying to access this other than the machine I am running the software on (my home PC)
- I also think that my IP address is not static.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just add a host entry corresponding to the IP address of your machine to all machines that need to address it using its FQDN. The hosts file can be found in `System32\Drivers\etc`. Just add an entry with your IP and the host to it, for example `192.168.0.1 mymachine.local`.

Another option would be setting up your own DNS server which is relatively harder. The biggest problem is presented by you not having a static IP address, you should either set a static IP or configure your DHCP server to reserve an IP for you based on your adapter's MAC address.

Comment: Works perfectly after setting up static IP.  Thanks